# bound for $|x|$ such that $|\operatorname{erf}(x)-1|<\varepsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, error-function

From the plot of the error function

[image]

we see that the function is close to $\pm1$ whenever $|x|\ge\frac32$ and "almost" $1$ when $|x|\ge2$. Can we give a (sharp) bound for $|x|$ such that $|\operatorname{erf}(x)-1|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Would recommend you define all of your functions and variables. What is erf(x)?

Comment: Try [inverse complementary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErfc.html)

Comment: Could you add some detail to your post, such as your attempt?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. There is something simpler

Answer (score 1):

$\def\erf{\operatorname{erf}} \def\erfc{\operatorname{erfc}} $

As Claude Leibovici
suggested,
here is the simple bound.

$\begin{array}\\
\erfc(x)
&=1-\erf(x)\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2}dt\\
&\lt\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{\infty} e^{-xt}dt
\qquad t^2>tx, -t^2<-xt\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x^2}^{\infty} e^{-y}\frac{dy}{x}
\qquad y=xt, dy=xdt, dt=\frac{dy}{x}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{x\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x^2}^{\infty} e^{-y}dy\\
&=\dfrac{2}{xe^{x^2}\sqrt{\pi}}\\
\end{array}
$

This is the first term of the
asymptotic series
for $\erfc(x)$.

So to have
$1-\erf(x) < c$
we can use
$\dfrac{2}{xe^{x^2}\sqrt{\pi}}\le c
$
or
$xe^{x^2}
\ge \dfrac{2}{c\sqrt{\pi}}
$.

This can be solved numerically.

Comment: It follows that $1 - \operatorname{erfc}(x) < \varepsilon$ if $$
x \ge \sqrt {\tfrac{1}{2}W\!\left( {\tfrac{8}{\pi }\varepsilon ^{ - 2} } \right)} 
$$ where $W$ is the principal branch of the Lambert $W$-function. A more explicit but less sharp bound is $$
x \ge \sqrt {\tfrac{1}{2}\left[ {\log \left( {\tfrac{8}{\pi }\varepsilon ^{ - 2} } \right) - \log \log \left( {\tfrac{8}{\pi }\varepsilon ^{ - 2} } \right)} \right]}.
$$